# Adding easting and northing points in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, fields-attributes, xy

I am trying to add coordinates into ArcGIS 10.6.1. Below are the Northing and Easting I have been given.

[image]

I have added these Northing and Eastings into an Excel sheet and saved them as a CSV File (The CSV has the other two coordinates not shown in the second image).

[image]

I then open Arc

> Add Data -->
> Add XY Data

The first confusion comes at this point when I am greeted with this.

[image]

When I select the drop down box for Latitude and Longitude, it give me 5 options for both **"X_Field"** and **"Y_Field"**

- **Point**
- **Longitude_x**
- **Longitude_Y**
- **Latitude_X**
- **Latitude_Y**

Why is this? When I open up the attribute table

After this I then save the layer as a shapefile, but when I go to reload the shapefile, there is no data points at all.

When I load the points in they produce a line of 4 points which can only be seen at 1:300 ratio (tiny). the points are also meant to be in a square not a line.

[image]

Can anyone tell me why I cant create these 4 simple locations into 4 points?

After listening to the comments, I used an online converter **https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/dms-decimal** to convert the degree-min-dec-sec data into lat/long.

Below are my results
[image]

From here I uploaded them into ArcGIS and got the desired shape I wanted (a simple box). the only issue is that when measuring the distance between the points it came out as seen below.

[image]

The issue here is that it is stating the distance between each point is 3m when the desired distance I need is around 10km, why is this happening?

Comment: Those coordinates are Degrees-Minutes-DecimalSeconds, You might try to convert to decimal degrees first.

Comment: Do you have a good online converter to change them into lat/long data?

Comment: @Vince - please see my new issue in the question, I have added edits now

Comment: Your question is very different now. Maybe you you ought to remove the inoperative things, to focus it on the current problem. Interactive measurement isn't the best way to calculate distances between points.

Answer (score 0):

Northings and Eastings are not the same as latitude and longitude (whether the lat long is in decimal or DMS). You can convert the N/Es to LatLong but you need to know the coordinate system. This would explain why the box is not the correct dimensions.